# What is the fundamental group in noncommutative geometry à la Efimov, Kaledin, Vologodsky?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the study of DG categories one encounters many different homologies. Is there an interesting notion of the fundamental group?

Comment: One should seek a notion of étale map in this context.

Comment: Seems somewhat unlikely to get pi_1, at least in isolation, since from a dg category (playing the role of coherent sheaves on a variety) you can't eg even recover the first cohomology group H^1, only the total odd cohomology H^{odd}.

Comment: The (étale as well as topological) fundamental group is not a derived invariant of algebraic varieties (https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/papers/gross-popescu.pdf) so any notion of fundamental group in the DG setting could not recover the classical one.